# AWS EventBridge putEvents does not accept Detail JSON array

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-js, aws-event-bridge

I am using AWS SDK `v2.796.0`

As per the documentation of putEvents, the Detail value needs to be a valid JSON string.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/APIReference/API_PutEventsRequestEntry.html

However, it is not accepting a JSON array as string.

```
    const eventBridge = new AWS.EventBridge();
    const entries = {
      Entries: [
        {
          EventBusName: "busName",
          Source: "api.user",
          DetailType: "detailType",
          Detail: JSON.stringify({ test: { test: ["test", "test2"] } }),
        },
      ],
    };
    const rs = await eventBridge.putEvents(entries).promise();
    console.log(rs);
    // this passes
    // {
    // FailedEntryCount: 0,
    // Entries: [ { EventId: 'a6176012-7310-2b84-a9b5-819956e2e3f9' } ]
    // }

    const entries2 = {
      Entries: [
        {

          EventBusName: "busName",
          Source: "api.user",
          DetailType: "detailType",
         Detail: JSON.stringify([{ test: "test" }]),
        },
      ],
    };
    const rs2 = await eventBridge.putEvents(entries2).promise();
    console.log(rs2);
    // this fails
    // {
    //    FailedEntryCount: 1,
    //    Entries: [
    //    {
    //      ErrorCode: 'MalformedDetail',
    //      ErrorMessage: 'Detail is malformed.'
    //     }
    //    ]
    //  }
```

Is this expected? Is there a way to use array in Detail?

Comment: @Marcin see the answer below. The workaround is to wrap the array in another object. 
E.g `Detail: JSON.stringify({events: ["test1", "test2"])`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This happens because you are using list in your `entries2`:

```
Detail: JSON.stringify([{ test: "test" }]),
```

If you just use object, it will work:

```
Detail: JSON.stringify({ test: "test" }),
```

Comment: Yeah. We have moved to that approach. But it seems as per documentation, both should work as `Detail` only needs to be a valid JSON string. Even a stringified list is a valid JSON string.

Comment: @RashidShaikh I know that list is valid json, but it seems that not for EventBridge.

Comment: Is there a way that can allow using arrays?